# How do I ping the original webpage, bypassing CDN?

Tags: web-services, ping

I live in Warsaw, Poland. I am pinging any US webpage (like www.nba.com):

```
$ ping www.nba.com
PING a1570.gd.akamai.net (213.155.152.161) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 213-155-152-161.customer.teliacarrier.com (213.155.152.161): icmp_req=1 ttl=58 time=6.90 ms
64 bytes from 213-155-152-161.customer.teliacarrier.com (213.155.152.161): icmp_req=2 ttl=58 time=5.68 ms
```

Time that I receive is around 7-10 ms, while distance from Poland to US and back (packages go forth and back) is around 16000 km (16*10^6 m). c=3*10^8 m/s. Distance/c = 0,05 s = 50ms.

So I suppose, that some webpages are cached on some other server e.g. in Western Europe (5ms, means less than 750km from my place). How than I can ping the original, US webpage then?

Or did I miss something?

EDIT1: Ok, I missed, I am pinging actually a1570.gd.akamai.net in London, but distance is still too far (>750km). Is it a ping time counter error?

Answer (score 0):

You are not pinging `www.nba.com` but one of CDN servers they are using, namely:

```
a1570.gd.akamai.net (213.155.152.161)
```

This Akamai server is [located in London](http://www.infosniper.net/index.php?ip_address=213.155.152.161&map_source=1&overview_map=1&lang=1&map_type=1&zoom_level=7). Hence your ping is so fast, proving CDN actually works.

Comment: London is still too far (>750km) Doesn it mean, linux's ping counts time in a bad manner? Still, the question is, how to ping the original site? Should I disable DNS and ping by IP?